# How to launch a command when compile in Android?

Tags: android, compilation

I need to run an application whenever android studio compile the application. The application automatically resizes all the images of xxx-dpi to mdpi and ldp. I need you to run in development and production.

You may do this from any configuration Gradle?

Comment: Yes, you can just add you own task to gradle and run it with each build. I highly suggest you start by reading the documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html